# How to have Admob ads in multiple Viewcontrollers - Swift, Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, admob

I am new to making apps. I am currently working on an app and I put a banner ad on the first view controller and it works. I can't find a way to add the ad to the rest of the view controllers. If someone can show me how that would be great!

Comment: Was my code useful to you? If so consider upvoting and accepting.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this code, if you need I can post with interstitial support too:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

protocol AdSimpleBannerPowered: UIViewController {
    var placeholder: UIView? { get }
    func addBannerToAdsPlaceholder(_ banner: UIView)
}

extension AdSimpleBannerPowered {
    func addBannerToAdsPlaceholder(_ banner: UIView) {
        placeholder?.addSubview(banner)
    }
}

private struct AdsConstants {
    static let admobAppID = "YOUR_APP_ID"
    static let adBottomBannerUnitID = "YOUR_BANNER_ID"
}

final class AdsManager : NSObject {
        
    var loadedSimpleBannerAd = false
    
    private var bannerView: GADBannerView?
    var rootViewController: UIViewController? {
        didSet {
            setupSimpleBannerAdsIfPossible()
        }
    }

    public override init() {
        super.init()
        
        GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start()
        
        configureSimpleBanner()
    }
    
    private func configureSimpleBanner() {
        bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
        bannerView?.delegate = self
        bannerView?.adUnitID = AdsConstants.adBottomBannerUnitID
    }
    
    private func setupSimpleBannerAdsIfPossible() {
        assert(self.bannerView != nil, "WTF: simple banner has not been configured (call Ads.configure() before any usage)!")
        if let root = rootViewController as? AdSimpleBannerPowered {
            if let banner = self.bannerView {
                banner.rootViewController = root
                if !loadedSimpleBannerAd {
                    banner.load(GADRequest())
                } else {
                    root.addBannerToAdsPlaceholder(banner)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}

// Simple Bottom Admob Banner delegate methods
extension AdsManager: GADBannerViewDelegate {
    
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
        loadedSimpleBannerAd = true
        if let root = rootViewController as? AdSimpleBannerPowered {
            root.addBannerToAdsPlaceholder(bannerView)
        }
    }
    
    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
                didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
}
```

Idea is to share one `GADBannerView` object across the app - so you don't spam Admob with every banner instantiation at each `UIViewController`

**Usage**

In each `UIViewController` you want the banner to be visible:

1. Conform to AdSimpleBannerPowered protocol
2. Add **placeholder** view at Storyboard or via code
3. Add `Ads.rootViewController = self` at `viewWillAppear()` method – that will instantiate and add the banner to placeholder.

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, AdSimpleBannerPowered {
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        Ads.rootViewController = self
    }

}
```

Comment: What would it be with Interstitial ads?